# Race Condition with LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, synchronization, android-livedata

**TL;DR of this Question:**

> Is it possible that a `LiveData` with a `backing property (MutableLiveData)` inside the ViewModel that is used to `Observe` and `Add` to an
> ArrayList can have a race condition and using `Synchronized` or a `Lock` is required?
> Provided that the ArrayList will get its value from a callback

I am trying to setup a group video call using the [Agora](https://www.agora.io/en) Android SDK. I followed the documentation [here](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/building-scalable-ui-for-android-using-agora/?utm_campaign=response&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=organic-social). The problem is with the `callbacks (onUserJoined, onUserOffline)` from **IRtcEngineEventHandler**.

> **OnUserJoined Callback**

```
mRtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(baseContext, APP_ID, object : IRtcEngineEventHandler() {
override fun onUserJoined(uid: Int, elapsed: Int) {
    // onUserJoined callback is called anytime a new remote user joins the channel
    super.onUserJoined(uid, elapsed)

    // We mute the stream by default so that it doesn't consume unnecessary bandwidth
    mRtcEngine?.muteRemoteVideoStream(uid, true)

    // We are using a lock since uidList is shared and there can be race conditions
    lock.lock()
    try {
        // We are using uidList to keep track of the UIDs of the remote users
        uidList.add(uid)
    } finally {
        lock.unlock()
    }
```

> **onUserOffline Callback**

```
override fun onUserOffline(uid: Int, reason: Int) {
    // onUserOffline is called whenever a remote user leaves the channel
    super.onUserOffline(uid, reason)

    // We use toRemove to inform the RecyclerView of the index of item we are removing
    val toRemove: Int

    // We are using a lock since uidList is shared and there can be race conditions
    lock.lock()
    try {
        // We are fetching the index of the item we are about to remove and then remove the item
        toRemove = uidList.indexOf(uid)
        uidList.remove(uid)
    } finally {
        lock.unlock()
    }
```

Here `Lock` is being used to access the `uidlist` in a `thread safe` way to prevent `race condition`. It was working for me when I followed the docs exactly, but when I tried to use a `LiveData` with a `backing property (MutableLiveData)` in a `ViewModel` for saving the `uidlist`, the observer on `uidlist` always returned an empty list.

> My ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
private val _uidList: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Int>> = MutableLiveData()
val uidList: LiveData<ArrayList<Int>> get() = _uidList

init {
    _uidList.value = ArrayList<Int>()
}

fun addToUserList(uid: Int) {
    _uidList.value?.add(uid)
    Log.d("adding user ","$uid")
}

fun removeFromUserList(uid: Int) {
    _uidList.value?.remove(_uidList.value!!.indexOf(uid))
}
```

}

I am calling `addToUserList()` inside `onUserJoined()` and `removeFromUserList()` inside the `onUserOffline()`

Please guide me to the solution to this problem,

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should not be mutating the value stored in `LiveData`, you'll get very strange behaviour. You have to swap the value out completely.

I'm feeling somewhat lazy so I will just give you the answer.

```kotlin
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {
private val _uidList: MutableLiveData<List<Int>> = MutableLiveData()
val uidList: LiveData<List<Int>> get() = _uidList

init {
    _uidList.value = emptyList<Int>()
}

fun addToUserList(uid: Int) {
    _uidList.value = (_uidList.value ?: emptyList()) + uid
    Log.d("adding user ","$uid")
}

fun removeFromUserList(uid: Int) {
    val value = _uidList.value?.toMutableList()
    if (value == null) return
    value.remove(value.indexOf(uid))
    _uidList.value = value
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I will try this solution and see if it fixes the issue!